# Rails "getting started" blog exercise console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I'm new to Rails, and I was working through the tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

When I got to the part about the console, I tried to replicate what they did, but I must have done something wrong, because when I try to load the page, I keep getting this :

[image]

I exited the console and restarted the server, but I still keep getting that error, but there are no changes I can see in the "post.rb" file that I could fix.

Is there a way for me to undo what I messed up in the console?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include your `post.rb` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a whitespace error

Instead of `validates: name`, it should be `validates :name`

It's subtle, but the first one is interpreted as a shortcut in Rails 1.9 as meaning `:validates => name` which isn't what you want.